# How to turn on notification for any incoming changes in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, source-control-explorer

TFS automatically updates my source control files without notify me what exactly has been updated. I want the compare tool automatically pops up and shows the changes from other people, even the change is not conflicting with mine. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To turn on notification for any incoming changes in TFS, the simplest way you can use is **Check in alert** You can receive email notifications when pending changes are checked in. You need to follow below steps:

1. Configure an SMTP sever to TFS  ( If your team already has ,doesn’t need)
2. Open alerts management, enter your Email Address.
3. Select New Alert Template, choose the alert types (For you , select Checkin  any checking occurs in this team project)

More detail from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334.aspx

If you get conflicts when you are checking in,you can use the diff window to resolve these conflicts  first.

Certainly, you  can also meet your customization requirement. But , there is not an easy way. You need to:

First ,you need to create a subscriber to license to the CheckIn event. 
Then use TFS API to call the diff window and get checked in files and changes associated with that changeset. Then show changes between local workspace and server version on the diff window .